# Check Default write disk in Android programmatically

Tags: android, storage

I know that we can set which storage is default, SDcard or internal storage in:

Settings -> Storage -> Default Write Storage.

How can I check which storage is "Default Write Storage" in Android programmatically?

I think if I check read/write permission on SDCard or phone storage path then I can find default storage but I don't know when you select sdcard  between sdcard and phone storage for default then you can't read/write on phone storage?

Is there any way to find this info in Android?